# `if i != _i and j != _j and k != _k:` continue but report the first occurrence?

Tags: python

I have such a condition check logic:

```
if k not in {None, i, j}: #don't reproduce itself   
    if i != _i and j != _j and k != _k: 
        continue #remove the identical copies    
    result = [num_1, num_2, num_3]
output.append(result)
```

However this solution will skip all the duplicates, I want a logic like

```
if i != _i and j != _j and k != _k:  #continue but add the first occurrence to output.
```

How could get it done?

the codes in leetcodes

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums, target: int=0) -> List[List[int]]:   
        lookup = {nums[i]:i for i in range(len(nums))} #overwrite from the high
        triplets = []
        triplets_set = set()

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            num_1 = nums[i]
            sub_target = target - num_1
            # logging.debug(f"level_1_lookup: {lookup}")

            for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
                num_2 = nums[j] #
                _j = lookup[num_2] #
                _i = lookup[num_1]
                _k = j + 1

                num_3 = sub_target - num_2              
                k = lookup.get(num_3) #             

                if k not in {None, i, j}: #don't reproduce itself   

                    if i != _i and j != _j and k != _k: continue #remove the identical copies 

                    result = [num_1, num_2, num_3]
                    result.sort()
                    result = tuple(result)
                    triplets_set.add(result)

        triplets = [list(t) for t in triplets_set]
        return triplets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check `output`, which you're already appending `result` to, to see if it contains the triple you're looking for. Something like this:

```
output = []
for i,j,k in some_iterable:
    if not [i, j, k] in output:
        output.append(result)
```

Alternatively, you could dedicate a separate variable to this purpose if you're using `output` for something else, or implement a boolean flag that starts `False` but turns `True` when you add the thing once.

Comment: `i`, `j`, and `k` aren't what's being added to `output` though.

Comment: then change the code I put in there to reflect your code. The underlying idea should still be valid.

Comment: I'm not the OP?